# Temporarily Disabling pager/month/week/day view in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to temporarily disable the pager left/right controls and the month/week/day view buttons in the calendar.  I don't want to permanently disable the calendar, but only temporarily as I have to wait as it refreshes some content.  There is a bit of HTML in the rendered HTML, so I'd thought I'd ask specifically what do I need to do to disable these features in a programmatic fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Per docs for header:

Can set any of the properties of the whole header to `false`, or not include header at all since defaults is `false`

Example for title only:

```
header: {
    left: false,
    center: 'title',
    right: false
}
```

API reference: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/

Comment: I didn't write my question correctly.  I need to temporarily disable the top bar, but need to enable it again after I reload some data.  Is the header something you can update after the fact, so that I could change the right side to the the agenda month/day/week view?  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".fc-header-left span.fc-button").addClass("ui-state-disabled");`, same for `.fc-header-right`...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have done this but only by using function based event source, so while fetching any data I put a div (to show the data loading effect/animation) on the whole page and removed that as soon as the fetching is done. following is the code:

```
                var eventSource = {
                events: function (start, end, callback) {
                    showHideloader(true, '');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "my.aspx/myEvents",
                        type: "POST",
                        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                        data: "{mydata:blabla}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var events = [];
                            var dateTime = new Date();
                            var jobs = eval("(" + data.d + ")");
                            $.each(jobs, function (i, val) {
                                events.push({
                                    id: jobs[i].TaskID,
                                    title: jobs[i].title,
                                    start: new Date(jobs[i].startDate)
                                });
                            });
                            callback(events);
                            showHideloader(false, '');
                        },
                        error: function (x, e) {
                            showMessage('error', 'failure loading tasks in calendar', x, e, true);
                            showHideloader(false, '');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }//event source

    //put a div on the page to show the data loading effect
    function showHideloader(_show) {
        if (_show) {
            $('#loader').height($(window).height());
            $('#loader').width($(window).width());
            $('#loader').css('top', '0');

            $('#loader').css('left', '0');
            //setting max possible z-index value to always show it in front
            $('#loader').css('z-index', '2147483640');
        }
        $('#loader').css('display', (_show) ? '' : 'none');
    }
```

In that I have made an event source object (no need to do so if you are already doing it in calendar call) and used a showHideloader just before the ajax call and again used it to enable the page in both success and failure cases.

Fo your reference I have included the code of showHideloader in which a dive with id='loader' is used to manipulate the diable/enable page effect.

Comment: You're calling `showHideLoader` with two parameters (`boolean` and an empty `string`) but your function only accepts one...